# Is determinant useful in representation of group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am learning representation theory of finite group, the trace of matrix is used to define character, which is very useful. the determinant of a matrix is also independent of choice of basis, is determinant of matrix useful in representation of group?

Comment: Philosophical (=useless) comment : in some sense you don't really need the determinant because it can be computed from the traces. More precisely, $x_1 \dots x_n$ is a polynomial in $x_1 + \dots + x_n, x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2, \dots, x_1^n + \dots + x_n^n$. The former is $\det(\rho(g))$ and the latter are $\text{tr}(\rho(g)), \text{tr}(\rho(g^2)), \dots, \text{tr}(\rho(g^n))$. This argument comes from the illuminating book by Fulton and Harris about representation theory.

Answer (score 5):

This is certainly a good observation and is applicable to character theory: if $\chi$ is a complex character of a finite group $G$, define $det(\chi): G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ as follows. Choose a representation $\mathfrak{X}$ affording $\chi$ and put $det(\chi)( g ) = det(\mathfrak{X})$. Then $det(\chi)$ is a uniquely defined linear complex character of $G$. This character is used in essential ways in many theorems, notably in relation to the order $o(\chi)$, of $det(\chi)$ now seen as an element of the group of linear characters of $G$. See for example the book *[Character Theory of Finite Groups](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MeE7BFXwQroC&printsec=frontcover&hl=nl&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)* by Marty Isaacs.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you know that $\det(\chi)$  $\textit{is}$ a character?

Comment: It is a homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$!

Comment: Oh goodness, of course... I will chalk that up to it being late :)
Thank you!